# How to use session per conversation strategy for managing transactions

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, transactions

How to use session per conversation strategy for managing transactions across EJB 3.1 Stateless BeanManaged Transaction.

Is it possible to use the Interceptors to manage transactions across EJBs?

Do we need to have the same interceptors for all EJBs?

Do we need to have the SFSB to store the disconnected session? If so, do we need to get the session in Interceptor or in next EJB itself?

With this can we manage the transaction committing only at the last method in the conversation and thereby maintaining the ACID property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to go for a Stateful Session Bean, configure the transactions as being managed at the bean level, start a transaction in the first method of the conversation and then, close it (commit/rollback) in the method annotated with @Remove.